# GCC compiler flag "-DEVAL"

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, gnu, compiler-flags

On some programming judges I found that their default GCC call is with flags:

```
-DEVAL -static -O2 -o
```

What does -DEVAL mean?

Comment: It defines a macro called `EVAL` like you would with `#define EVAL`

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options

Comment: @Viktor, Yes, according to the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI:  this is how to print all the available macro definitions:

```
gcc -E -dD -x c /dev/null -o -
```

Compare it with

```
gcc -E -DEVAL -dD -x c /dev/null -o -
```